# JAVA Scanner // Why my object can t get input?

Tags: java, object, input, java.util.scanner

**Greetings Gentelmens ;**
So i have an object MilkBottle and i want to give it an input using the java scanner. Where is my error ?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyClassBottle{

 String material;
 String volume;

 public static void main(String[] args){
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
 MyClassBottle MilkBottle = new MyClassBottle();
 System.out.println("Enter bottle material: ");
 Scanner one = MilkBottle.material, next();
 System.out.println("Enter bottle volume:  ");
 Scanner two = MilkBottle.volume, next();

System.out.println(MilkBottle.material);
System.out.println(MilkBottle.volume);

 }
}
```

I am still a noob so don t blame too much for my code !

P.s. Thank you in advance !

Comment: What is this `Scanner one = MilkBottle.material, next();`

Comment: You should create only one `Scanner` instance and use its `next` method to get the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not valid Java. You need to use *assignments* to assign the *return values* of the scanner:

```
MyClassBottle MilkBottle = new MyClassBottle();
System.out.println("Enter bottle material: ");
MilkBottle.material = input.next();
System.out.println("Enter bottle volume:  ");
MilkBottle.volume = input.next();
```

That being said, the goal of this website is to make the asker a better programmer, so I'll point out other things that can be improved:

- Naming conventions: Class names are capitalized, variable names are not. `MyClassBottle MilkBottle = new MyClassBottle();` should be `MyClassBottle milkBottle = new MyClassBottle();` and all accesses to `MilkBottle` should get the lowercase name.
- Types: As `String`, your bottle's volume could be "1.2", "100000000000000", "15L", or "green eggs and ham". You should use a more useful type for this like `int` for integers or `double` for decimal values, and use `nextInt()` or `nextDouble()` on the scanner instead.
- [Constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) can be used to more cleanly create instances of `MyClassBottle`. Read scanner input to local variables then pass to constructor,